# Riley pays a visit

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My Prefix works solo,My infix will disagree,
>
> My suffix is the end, now tell me where I be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are in

> Northern Germany.

My Prefix works solo,

> Han

My infix will disagree,

> no

My suffix is the end,

> over

now tell me where I be.

> Hanover :)

Comment: and you take away the cake, kudos

Comment: I have an edit suggestion for your answer: you have to add another "n" between the prefix and the infix. That's the correct spelling :)

Comment: I prefer adding a "g"

Comment: @jafe I was just gonna say the same thing :D

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is:

> Monopole or monopoly
>  Mono = one, single, only so it could be considered a synonym of solo
>  Nope = as a disagreement
>  Pole = like North or South pole, i.e. the end of the world, or the end of the Earth's axis.
>  So you are either on one of the poles or you are in a game of Monopoly, maybe?

Comment: nice answer, but not quite what i have in mind.